# Dynamic height for DIV

Tags: css

I have the following DIV

```
<div id="products">

</div>

#products
{
    height: 102px; width: 84%;
    padding:5px; margin-bottom:8px;
    border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
}
```

Now inside the DIV, I am dynamically generating 4 links. But sometimes there could be more or less than 4 links. How can I change the CSS to dynamically resize the DIV according to its contents?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

set  `height: auto;` If you want to have minimum height to x then you can write

```
height:auto;
min-height:30px;
height:auto !important;        /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
height:30px;                   /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
```

Answer (score 2):

calculate the height of each link no do this

```
document.getElementById("products").style.height= height_of_each_link* no_of_link
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me as-
HTML-

```
    <div style="background-color: #535; width: 100%; height: 80px;">
        <div class="center">
            Test <br>
            kumar adnioas<br>
            sanjay<br>
            1990
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS-

```
.center {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 82%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
```

Hope will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be okay to just take the height property out of the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Set both to `auto`:

```
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

Making it:

```
#products
{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding:5px; margin-bottom:8px;
    border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as prior ans remove the height attrib. if u want your expansion along with its min height then use `min-height: 102px` instead of `height: 102px.`

note ie 6 and min-height http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/