# Can not stretch the css divs 100 % vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout, stretch

I am trying to convert my table design to css div design.

What does not work:

1.)
The black div will have list items therefore I need scrollbars which is shown at the moment. Thats fine.
But I do not want to limit the height to 400px. My former design had 100% for the height so it takes all vertical space on the screen.

2.) The red div (rightContent) should have a fixed width of 200px; When I set this what do I have to set, that the leftContent takes all horizontal space.

Above all in the old table layout were no outer vertical scrollbar visible around the whole layout.

I tested this on IE9

http://jsfiddle.net/pEMwP/4/

Comment: This may help for 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075440/dynamic-height-for-div

Comment: And just so I'm clear, you're looking to get the purple, yellow, black, and orange fields to take 100% of the window width?

Comment: purple,yellow,black. orange not. I did height:auto but then no scrollbars are visible. because the div stretches down into the browser.

Comment: For 'height-auto', you'll need to set a 'height-max' to set when your scroll bars will pop up.  This still sets a limit to height but if at least you won't get a big blank space if there is little text in the black field. Also, where should the orange field be in relation to red? To the left or on top?

Comment: the orange div should be to the left. Should I set the height-max on the black div,but what px should I set, I do not know its max height.

Comment: I do NOT want to use max-height because this will fix the height of the black div. When I resize the browser window and increase its height, the black div should increase too.

Comment: Hmm, you're going to have to make a design decision as to what height you like the scroll bars to appear.  I used 350px in your code above and it looked ok. If you feel that you don't necessarily need scroll bars then you can just leave it on auto.

Answer (score 0):

**For Question1:** 
If you want a scrollbar, you should not set the height property to auto. Instead you can dynamically set the Div height via Javascript like this.

```
document.getElementById("ListData").style.height=<your Size>;
```

**For Question 2:** 
If you want to set height to Red Div. You can specify like this.

```
height: 200px;
overflow:hidden;
```

this will limit the div to 200px. Now you can increase your other div/divs width to occupy this space .

Comment: come on no javascript! and why should I set my height to 200px to make the horizontal space working? Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

If I was starting something like this from scratch I'd rethink the layout so I didn't have such tight constraints, but as you're converting an existing site I appreciate this might not be an option.

You could use the `display: table;`, `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell`; declarations to get a semantically correct (it's not tabular data, right?) structure which behaves just like the oft misused `<table>` of yore. Admittedly, you'd have to implement some work-around for IE6&7 (probably 2-3% of users), but perhaps you could accept that it's usable but imperfect in those browsers?

http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/