# get height of div from masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the height of a `div` which is placed inside a masterpage?

I'm able to set the height as follow:

```
((HtmlControl)this.Master.FindControl("sidebar")).Style.Add("height", "600px");
```

Now I'm trying to get the height from my `div` called `mainPage`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MasterPage.Master:

```
<div id="_test" style="height: 100px" runat="server"></div>
```

MasterPage.Master.cs:

```
public HtmlGenericControl test
{
    get { return this._test; }
}
```

any other cs-file:

```
string width = ((MasterPage)this.Master).test.style["height"];
```

**Edit**: If you want to get any style information created dynamically you will need to store this information into a hidden field, because you won't be able to retrieve the data by calling style["x"] in the postback.

**Edit2**: Adjusted masterpage-name.

Comment: This will give the value of the `width` CSS property but not the actual height of the `div` BTW.

Comment: hi, i cant get find (MainTemplate),

Comment: You need to fill in the name of your Masterpage.

Comment: this statement is not working,
MainTemplate is not recognized

string width = ((MainTemplate)this.Master).test.style["height];

Comment: What is the name of your Masterpage?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: If you don't set a style before running the project (aka in the aspx-file) you won't be able to retrieve this information on postback. In addition you won't get any changed style no matter what you do. You'll then need javascript/jQuery. I advise you to clarify your problem, as both Yannick Blondeau and me are fishing in the dark.

Comment: i have set the style size, but in a .css file, ille try this directly in the aspx page and see if this helps

Comment: oki, now im able to retrieve the height with both method, but i only get the size i have set, not the current size after pageload

Comment: the thing is, the div tag is emptey, but when the page loads, it gets populated with a gridview, which increases the height of the div, and thats the height i want

Comment: If you set a size, then it is fixed. If you change the size to x then you already know x. If you set no size, then the div takes space depending on controls inside of it. It is still unclear to me what you want to get: a) the value of the style-height b) the height of a dynamic div

Comment: i want the height of a dynamic div i guess,
because after the div is filled with the grid, the height is not the same that i set, it will change as the gridview gets more data bound.

Comment: First you'll need to change your css (see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075440/dynamic-height-for-div) then you need to retrieve the value with javascript/jQuery (I prefer jQuery) and send it back in the postback so you can handle it in your .cs-file. You can do it by a <asp:Hiddenfield> where you set the value with jQuery.

Comment: really want to avoid using jquerry.

Comment: I'd say that this is impossible, because the data is rendered on client side.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the div's height on the client side as it may be rendered differently for each client...

Using jQuery, you can do

```
$("#sidebar").height();
```

but for this you will have to wait that the document is ready. So you can put this line in the `ready` function of the `document`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

**EDIT**

Another solution is adding `runat="server"` to your `div`

```
<div ID="sidebar" runat="server">...</div>
```

Then from your code you can do something like

```
HtmlGenericControl sb = this.form1.FindControl("sidebar") as HtmlGenericControl;
int sidebarHeight = sb.Height;
```

Comment: is this not possible with c# code ?, dont know jQuery, so i would like an answer in c# code, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the `width` CSS property or the actual height of the `div`?

Comment: im trying to get the current height of the div, not the css property which is set

Comment: Yannick Blondeau: still getting null value

Comment: the thing is, the div tag is emptey, but when the page loads, it gets populated with a gridview, which increases the height of the div, and thats the height i want

Comment: Try to use a [`Panel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) instead of the `div`. It renders as a `div` anyway...